# Show multiple lines with QTabBar

Tags: qt

I am working with Qt and met some troubles recently with `QTabBar`. By default, it shows all the tabs in a single line with arrows to switch between. That doesn't satisfy my client. Tabs must be shown in several lines, as many lines as needed to contain given tabs. If one line is enough, then just one line, but otherwise it will be 2,3 or more.

I didn't find any property or function that is responsible for this. How can I achieve this?

Comment: please add your code

Comment: This has long been a Qt feature request because it's such a bear to implement. You'll need to roll your own or find a third party solution, such a as Evgeny's answer.

Answer (score 2):

`QTabBar` doesn't have such functionality. You should implement your own widget or look for third-party solutions.

For example, we have such a widget in Psi+ XMPP client. Some related code you can find [here](https://github.com/psi-plus/psi-plus-snapshots/blob/master/src/widgets/tabbar.cpp).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. There is a feature request open for it, see https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-2061